# Java library to generate Postgres SQL Script from DB

Tags: java, api, postgresql

Good day, everybody!

Straight to the point.
Is there any java library to generate Postgres SQL Script from DB?

For example i have table job_table

```
   name    | job
   Andy    | pull
   Benny   | push
```

Then, i wanna get the String sql-script like this

```
String sqlInsert = 

  "INSERT INTO job_table(name, job) VALUES ('Andy', 'pull');"+
  "INSERT INTO job_table(name, job) VALUES ('Benny', 'push');";
```

Or something kind like that.

Anybody know?

Nb: I have wrote my own code in java to generate it manually. 
    But i just don't like it. :)

Thanks before.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the pg_dump utility to back up the database directly?

Comment: yes, i wanna use that String for my webservice so that the client can get it and execute it directly. I know we can give the client with other format, example:json or xml, but for some reason i must give that String to my client

Comment: Will COPY via JDBC do (see answer) or do you strictly need INSERTs? If so, there's no easy alternative to pg_dump at the moment, you'd probably have to shell out to "pg_dump --data-only --table=sometable" and read its stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Use the PgJDBC support for the COPY command to feed tab-delimited or CSV data into the database, and to extract it in the same format. You want the [CopyManager](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html), which can be obtained from a [PgConnection](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGConnection.html).

The CopyManager is rather woefully under-documented at present, but it's just a wrapper around the [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command.

Get access to the `PgConnection` interface by casting your java.sql.Connection to `PgConnection`. If the connection is wrapped by a connection pooling service you may have to unwrap it to get the real underlying connection returned by PgJDBC. Same deal if you're using JPA, you'll have to get access to the real PgJDBC connection or make a new one.

If you actually need `INSERT` statements, rather than an efficient way of delivering data to the database, what are your specific needs? Portability? If so, how will you handle things like the different representations of NUMERIC / DECIMAL / whatever?

If you only need to handle the "standard" data types, your hand rolled code may be the best way.

The only strictly safe way to do that is currently via pg_dump. You can invoke a `pg_dump --data-only --table=thetable` process and read from its stdout to do the job, though this does require (a) direct knowledge of the DB details in the app, not just a DataSource or injected entity manager from a container; (b) knowledge of the pg_dump path, and (c) the security permission to execute external processes. Unfortunately there isn't really any way around that at present. pg_dump isn't designed to be used as a library (though there's been talk of converting it) and even if it were, it'd be a C library you'd have to wrap via JNI or similar. Ick.